# Starting an Application via LaunchPad vs. starting via Alias from Console

Tags: launchpad, alias

Mac Mini Monterey:

I have defined an Alias "jedit" to jEdit.app. If I start "jedit" from the commandline, jEdit starts and allows to edit all of my files. If I start jEdit by clicking on "jEdit.app" in the Applications-Folder, jEdit starts but most folders can not be read. I cannot modify anything.

What can I do?

Comment: This sounds like a permission problem. Does the JVM used by jEdit have access to all folders (can be set in System Preferences)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My preferred Editor is jEdit which is implemented in Java. On my Mac mini, initially almost everything went more or less well. The problem arose, after having installed an actual Java Engine on Saturday.

Initially the JVM could not be found. Consequently jEdit could not be launched. After having fixed that problem, jEdit could only read file from the "Development"-Directory, when started via Launchpad. The behaviour is completely different, wenn jEdit is started via commandline by the mentioned Alias.

To get jEdit working properly again, it is necessary to perform some several funny steps, which are not documented and not really understandable.

#### Step 1

```
cd /Application/jEdit.app/Contents/PlugIns
ln -s <directory_to-jdk> jdk
cd ..
```

Edit Info.plist and add the following lines somewhere in the file

```
<key>JVMRuntime</key>
<string>jdk</string>
```

#### Step 2

```
cd ~/Library
sudo chmod a+w Application\ Support
```

Comment: Do you have a reference/link for this? Not sure about step 1, but step 2 for sure is not required (and actually not a good idea as it allows any user to write to that directory).

Comment: Sorry, I do not want to link to my engine.
And, both steps were necessary. Step 1) was needed, to find the JVM, which was installed by an Apple-pkg. I did expect, that Apple takes care of necessary permissions. I am the owner of my engine, and all users (me) should have write access to all folders. This was the reason (step2) to allow access to my folders for everyone: For me.
Any other ideas are welcome.
To be honest, I do not understand the different behaviors, when starting an application via an alias from the command line or via the "famous" launchpad.

Comment: By engine you mean computer? You as a user already have write access to `~/Library/Application Support`, so `chmod a+w ...` (which gives access to *all* users on the computer) doesn't change anything for you. That's why it seems to be unnecessary in your case.

Comment: And with reference/link, I was wondering whether you got the information from somewhere else (and if yes, please share the link to that page).

Comment: May be, but after having changed the permission rights, I am able to work on my engine, my computer with my preferred tool again.